# Determining probability of a normal random variable at a single point?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I tried to do this exercise from A first course in probability by Sheldon Ross:

> An image is partitioned into two regions, one
>   white and the other black. A reading taken from
>   a randomly chosen point in the white section will
>   give a reading that is normally distributed with $μ =
> 4$ and $σ^2 = 4$, whereas one taken from a randomly chosen point in the black region will have a normally
>   distributed reading with parameters $(6, 9)$.
>   A point is randomly chosen on the image and has
>   a reading of $5$. If the fraction of the image that is
>   black is $α$, for what value of α would the probability
>   of making an error be the same, regardless of
>   whether one concluded that the point was in the
>   black region or in the white region?

My attempt at the problem:

Let $A$ be the event that the chosen point has a reading of $5$, and $B$ that it's in the black region.
We need to show that $P(B\mid A)=P(B'\mid A)$, which is equivalent to $P(B\mid A)=\frac12$.

We know that

$$P(B\mid A)=\frac{P(B)P(A\mid B)}{P(B)P(A\mid B)+P(B')P(A\mid B')}$$

Here is my problem. Isn't $P(A)=0$, because of the normal random variable being continuous? If so, how can I compute $P(A\mid B)$ and $P(A\mid B')$? Or maybe my whole approach is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't compute the conditional probability mass, you use the conditional probability density.

$$\mathsf P(B\mid A) =\dfrac{\mathsf P(B)f(A\mid B)}{\mathsf P(B)f(A\mid B)+\mathsf P(B')f(A\mid B')}$$

Where $f(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\exp(-(5-4)^2/8)}{\sqrt{8\pi~}}$, $f(A\mid B') = \dfrac{\exp(-(5-6)^2/18)}{\sqrt{18\pi~}}$

Comment: Thank you. This is weird though because conditional probability density is introduced later in the book. But do I understand correctly that you basically changed the event $(X=5)$ to $(5-\epsilon<X<5+\epsilon)$, where $X$ is a normal random variable, and then used the fact that $P(5-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<X<5+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\approx f(5)\epsilon$?

Comment: @bg5 It's basically applying l'Hopital's Rule to $$\mathbf P(B\mid A) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\dfrac{\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(5-\epsilon<X<5+\epsilon\mid B)}{\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(5-\epsilon<X<5+\epsilon\mid B)+\mathsf P(B')~\mathsf P(5-\epsilon<X<5+\epsilon\mid B')}$$

Comment: I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The normal distribution with expectation $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi\,}} \exp\left( \frac{-1} 2 \left( \frac{x-\mu} \sigma \right)^2 \right) \, \frac{dx} \sigma.
$$

Here's what I would do after that:
\begin{align}
& \frac{\Pr(\text{black}\mid \text{data})}{\Pr(\text{white}\mid \text{data})}
= \frac{\Pr(\text{black})}{\Pr(\text{white})} \cdot \frac{\frac 1 {\sigma_1} \exp\left( \frac{-1} 2 \left( \frac{x-\mu_1} {\sigma_1} \right)^2 \right) }{\frac 1 {\sigma_2} \exp\left( \frac{-1} 2 \left( \frac{x-\mu_2} {\sigma_2} \right)^2 \right)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\Pr(\text{black})}{\Pr(\text{white})} \cdot \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1} \cdot \exp\left( \frac{-1} 2 \left( \left( \frac{x-\mu_1} {\sigma_1} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{x-\mu_2} {\sigma_2} \right)^2 \right) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\Pr(\text{black})}{\Pr(\text{white})} \cdot \frac 3 2 \cdot \exp\left( \frac{-1} 2 \left( \frac 1 9 - \frac 1 4 \right) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \alpha {1 - \alpha} \cdot \frac 3 2 \cdot \exp\left( \frac 5 {72} \right).
\end{align}
(Here I used $\mu_1=6$, $\sigma_1=3$, $\mu_2 =4$, $\sigma_2 = 2$, $x=5$.)

Now set that equal to $1$ and solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you, but I think the expectations and standard deviations should be swapped and it should equal $1$, not $\frac{1}{2}$, am I right?

Comment: @bg5 : You're right: Those two should be swapped. $\qquad$

Comment: @bg5 : Done. $\quad{{{}}}\quad$